# Will duplicate "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" headers break CORS?

Tags: ajax, https, http-headers, cors

So we have an http resource that serves up JSON. It adds an

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

flag. So this can be loaded with CORS... *except* (so I'm told) there's some IE9 quirk that means this still won't work in IE9, but it would work if this were an https resource.

So we set up an existing https proxy to include this resource. Only that https resource was ALSO adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header, so the response contains TWO such headers.

And this seems not to work at all. Experimentally it looks like if I remove the header from the "inner" http resource, the proxied version (now containing just the one header) does work. Just testing with jQuery CORS in Chrome, Firefox.

Is that right? So all I need to do is (have somebody) fix the https proxy to "set" the header and not of "add" it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [CORS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) explicitly states that:

> If the response includes zero or more than one
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header values, return fail and terminate
>   this algorithm.

So you are correct, you should only have a single `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: The spec talks about duplicate header **values** I'm not sure this is relevant for duplicate headers.

Comment: I interpreted it as duplicate values regardless of whether the values are in the same header, or across multiple headers.

Comment: True if the headers have different values, but if they have the same value (exact duplicate headers) then it's a different story, I just thought it's important to point this out in a comment so people will understand if they encounter this.

Answer (score 2):

If the duplicate headers have different values then they will be concatenated into one value. That, as monsur pointed out, will cause the header to be invalid, as stated in the spec.

Having a duplicate header with the same value might work with some clients (Chrome let's that pass, at least at the time of writing) but as the [Mozilla Developer Network says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin):

> A returned resource may have one Access-Control-Allow-Origin header...

So, one header to control them all.

Answer (score 0):

The most of time the problem it's the duplication  into the headers of the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` (Apache Bug). My solution it's to put into **.htaccess** these lines.

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*(\.yoursite.com)[:0-9]*)$" cors=$1
# wash out these headers in the 'onsuccess' table if we get them from the backend
Header onsuccess unset Access-Control-Allow-Origin env=cors
Header onsuccess unset Access-Control-Allow-Credentials env=cors
Header onsuccess unset Access-Control-Allow-Methods env=cors
Header onsuccess unset Access-Control-Allow-Headers env=cors
# add them to the 'always' table
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{cors}e env=cors
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true" env=cors
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" env=cors
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "accept,x-requested-method,origin" env=cors
```

and it's working fine!